# How do I create a basic program to use as a Token-22 transfer hook in Anchor? Is it even possible now?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, anchor-lang, token-2022

I want to create a counter PDA that counts the number of times a token has been transferred. I understand how to create the counter PDA using the Solana Playground tutorial as the basis and I know how to create and mint token-22 tokens using the CLI. I assume the transfer hook would need to know the correct entrypoint to execute upon transfer but I cannot see where this would be defined. If this is currently not possible in Anchor please let me know as well.

Here is the program for reference:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("8f9DYpQbCkCvKgWkafcNBjBxS5aH1dTtEXcdqTDGr3Q1");

#[program]
// Smart contract functions
pub mod counter {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_counter(ctx: Context<CreateCounter>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Creating a Counter!!");

        // The creation of the counter must be here
        let counter = &mut ctx.accounts.counter;
        counter.authority = ctx.accounts.authority.key();
        counter.count = 0;
        msg!("Current count is {}", counter.count);
        msg!("The Admin PubKey is: {} ", counter.authority);

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn update_counter(ctx: Context<UpdateCounter>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Adding 1 to the counter!!");

        // Updating the counter must be here 
        let counter = &mut ctx.accounts.counter;
        counter.count += 1 ;
        
        msg!("Current count is {}", counter.count);
        msg!("{} remaining to reach 1000 ", 1000 - counter.count);

        Ok(())
    }

}

// Data validators
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateCounter<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 100
    )]
    counter: Account<'info, Counter>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateCounter<'info> {
    authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, has_one = authority)]
    counter: Account<'info, Counter>,
}

// Data structures
#[account]
pub struct Counter {
    authority: Pubkey,
    count: u64,
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are two references of transfer hook programs built using Anchor!

https://github.com/0ximalice/spl-token-2022-transfer-hook-anchor

https://github.com/TeamRaccoons/raccoons-program-library/tree/main/permissioned-token

It looks like the solution is to use a `fallback` instruction in Anchor to  work around the instruction discriminator.

Here's the fallback instructions for the two references:

[First reference](https://github.com/0ximalice/spl-token-2022-transfer-hook-anchor/blob/main/programs/transferhook/src/lib.rs#L74-L86):

```
// Sha256(spl-transfer-hook-interface:execute)[..8]
pub const EXECUTE_IX_TAG_LE: [u8; 8] = [105, 37, 101, 197, 75, 251, 102, 26];

...

    pub fn fallback(program_id: &Pubkey, accounts: &[AccountInfo], ix_data: &[u8]) -> Result<()> {
        let mut ix_data: &[u8] = ix_data;
        let sighash: [u8; 8] = {
            let mut sighash: [u8; 8] = [0; 8];
            sighash.copy_from_slice(&ix_data[..8]);
            ix_data = &ix_data[8..];
            sighash
        };
        match sighash {
            EXECUTE_IX_TAG_LE => {__private::__global::transfer_hook(program_id, accounts, ix_data)},
            _ => Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData.into()),
        }
    }
```

[Second reference](https://github.com/TeamRaccoons/raccoons-program-library/blob/main/permissioned-token/programs/permissioned-token/src/lib.rs#L71-L85):

```
/// The fallback allows routing methods to match the transfer hook interface
    pub fn fallback(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &[AccountInfo],
        instruction_data: &[u8],
    ) -> Result<()> {
        if let Err(error) = processor::process(program_id, accounts, instruction_data) {
            // catch the error so we can print it
            error.print::<TransferHookError>();
            return Err(error.into());
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible at the moment. Anchor always generates the instruction discriminator the same way, by appending `global:` to the instruction name, taking the sha256 hash, and then taking the first 8 bytes [1].

To implement a transfer hook, your program needs to accept instruction data fitting the predefined discriminator for the transfer hook program, which is the first 8 bytes of the sha256 hash of `spl-transfer-hook-interface:execute` [2].

You can start with the example program and adapt it to your needs [3].

[1] https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/243ab7573865a7296dd2af1153f44bffbf488458/lang/syn/src/codegen/program/instruction.rs#L25

[2] https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/88547d85c1cbe63feb2f79160d3070075a9e156a/token/transfer-hook-interface/src/instruction.rs#L54

[3] https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token/transfer-hook/example